# How to cite an old paper?

Tags: citations, paper-submission, citation-style

My first article was accepted with minor revisions, one of them being the correction of a citation. This citation points to the first time the method I am improving was proposed, which was 1962.

Here is a link to the Paper : http://www-isl.stanford.edu/~widrow/papers/c1961generalizationand.pdf

It is on the Stanford online library. I found this paper cited multiple times in the following way:

> B. Widrow, ``Generalization and Information Storage in Networks of
>   Adaline `Neurons','' in Self-Organizing Systems, symposium
>   proceedings, M.C. Yovitz, G.T. Jacobi, and G. Goldstein, eds.,
>   pp.435-461, Spartan Books, Washington, DC, 1962.

So I used it, but the reviewers are still asking me for a revision as they deem it to be incorrect. So my

**Question:**

How to cite this paper in a Periodica Polytechnica journal ?

---

**EDIT 1 :**

Thank you for your help, They didn't point to a particular correction, here is a print screen of their comment :

[image]

Comment: What did they say was incorrect about the citation?  Are they suggesting that you should be citing some earlier publication?  Are they suggesting that this isn't correct bibliographic information for this publication?

Comment: There must be some fussy technicality they object to... or it doesn't fit into some limited list of templates... or something subject-matter-irrelevant. The only way to figure out what the heck they want is by asking directly. There is no way to _deduce_ "by reason" what formatting issue is being objected-to.

Comment: Was it the reviewers that complain about citation (in that case, it sounds more likely that you should cite a different/additional paper), or was it the editor/production team (in that case, ask the editor/team for help)

Comment: First, i would like to thank you gentlemen, i will go with your advice and contact the editor directly, since it is at a production level, Thank you again.

Comment: I believe https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/142666/22768 provides a correct answer. Beyond that, the URL in the screenshot doesn't match http://www-isl.stanford.edu/~widrow/papers/c1961generalizationand.pdf, which should probably be fixed if the URL will be included. As an alternative solution, you could drop the URL entirely, since there's no need to provide a URL to a personal website (which will become obsolete), when you cite a published work.

Comment: You should change the title of the question: It is not connected to how old your source is.

Comment: Concerning Snijderfrey's comment: I'd suggest something like "Copy editor asks to correct a citation. What should I change here?" (Remember that the title of the question should be helpful to other people with a similar problem.)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this doesn't look like a reviewer's comment, but rather like a copy-editor's comment. And if I interpret the comment correctly, they just want a note that indicates when the resource was last accessed for all online resources. So you only have to add "(Accessed 10 January 2020)" after the URL.
This is completely unrelated to the age of the paper.

Answer (score 3):

If they're objecting to your citation style, don't worry. They are hardly going to recommend rejection because your citation style is wrong (or even if they do the editor is unlikely to actually reject for that reason). The journal's production staff will fix it for you if/after your paper is accepted.